# Can't load txt file of dependecy in Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I'm making simple package that edits and provides data, saved in txt file.
Since I can't import non-script files(JSON, txt, etc..), I'm using `Deno.open()`.

[**sample.txt (In package)**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/sample.txt)

```
Hello, World!
```

[**mod.ts (In package)**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/mod.ts)

```ts
const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8")

const f = await Deno.open("sample.txt")
export default decoder.decode(await Deno.readAll(f)) // Hello, World!
f.close()
```

Package runs fine alone, but make error when it is used in other directory.
**test.ts (Local file, loads the package in different directory)**

```ts
import file from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/mod.ts"

console.log(file)
```

error:

```sh
$ deno -V
deno 1.2.0
$ deno run --allow-read test.ts
Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/mod.ts
Compile file:///var/task/__$deno$eval.ts
error: Uncaught NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async Object.open ($deno$/files.ts:37:15)
    at async https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/mod.ts:3:11
```

It seems like deno downloads script files only.
[(generated file image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emKHl.png)
I just want to make deno load non-script data files too.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the file for sure there? Because I run the same code without any problem. See Screenshots:

https://imgur.com/a/hBwoxi8

Comment: @Atomzwieback I meant: load the package in different directory. I edited my question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, it's important to check the error:

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It's telling you that `"sample.txt"` does not exist on the current directory. Make sure you're executing Deno from the directory where the file is present.

---

Aside from that for reading text files you can use `Deno.readTextFile` instead

```
export default await Deno.readTextFile("./sample.txt") // Hello, World!
```

---

Your code expects `sample.txt` to be on your filesystem, but you're trying to read `sample.txt` from the github repository, the only solution would be to perform an HTTP request to fetch that file, instead of using Deno filesystem APIs.

But in that case, you won't be able to write to it. For your use case, you should work with local files, so you'll need to create the file if it doesn't exist if you're going to write to it.

> I'm making simple package that edits and provides data, saved in txt file.

Comment: I want to use the package, in other directory. I apologize for the unclear wording. I edited my question.

Comment: show file structure, and where is "sample.txt" located, otherwise it's impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: "mod.ts" and "sample.txt" are in github repo https://github.com/gnlow/deno-file-test . "test.ts" is in my local folder. "test.ts" loads "mod.ts" from github https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnlow/deno-file-test/master/mod.ts

Comment: Okay, you can't load a file using Deno.open that you don't have on your file system.

Comment: Check updated answer, you can't use filesystem APIs to write to a remote file. Your code should be changed, I don't know what functionality you're looking to implement but as of now it doesn't make much sense, unless you actually have a `sample.txt` created locally.